# How to mount USB flash drive to WINE?

Tags: wine

I download YUMI from pendrivelinux.com, the website tell me I can use WINE to run it ( using WINE from default repo on raring), but when I run it my USB drive wont show up on YUMI, I have tried to unmount the usb drive in ubuntu but still it not available on YUMI.\

UPDATE:
error using multisystem after clicking confirm:
[image]

Comment: I don't think Wine has access to USB ports. May I ask what are you trying to accomplish? Because if you just want to create a bootable USB drive, you can use the _Startup Disk Creator_ already included in Ubuntu, or you could use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), which is similar to YUMI and has a Linux version. If you're looking to use YUMI to create a bootable USB with multiple OSs, you can visit this page from pendrivelinux: [MultiSystem – Create a MultiBoot USB from Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/).

Comment: I want to create multiboot USB drive which consist of Windows 7 and Ubuntu, I know YUMI can do that because I've use it before under Windows, I thought it will working on WINE because I found "Windows XP/Vista/7 or WINE to create the Bootable USB" on its website. Does Multiboot can create boot loader for Windows 7 ISO like YUMI do?

Comment: @Alaa I got error when using Multisystem, please see update.

Answer (score 7):

Good news: Wine supports USB flash drives!
Even more good news: it might be super easy!
1. run `winecfg`
2. go to the "Drives" tab
3. click "Add..."
4. chose your favorite letter
5. find the "Path:" text field and click the "Browse..." button next to that
6. find wherever your operating system has mounted the flash drive. In Ubuntu it'll be under /media
7. select your flash drive's mount point (if you're using YUMI it'll probably be called "MULTIBOOT".
8. click "OK" and then "OK" again.
9. Run YUMI or whetever Windows program you were using your flash drive with.

If that doesn't work for you, you might have to patch in USB support and then compile WINE yourself, according to this: https://web.archive.org/web/20160117115117/http://wiki.winehq.org:80/USB
If you want to go that route, the website makes it sound simple enough.
1. open a terminal
2. type `wine --version`
3. go here and click on your version number: ftp://ftp.etersoft.ru/pub/people/amorozov/usb/
4. download the two text files to your wine source folder
5. run `patch -p1 < 0001*.txt` and then `patch -p1 < 0002*.txt`
6. build it

That last step is what kills it for me, because I'm a noob and half of every compile attempt finds me in dependency hell. The website also says "Only for versions before 1.1.22. Run `tools/make_makefiles`" before building it. I don't knowú what that means, but it might be useful.

Thankfully the first option worked for me.
I feel it's worth noting that while adding another OS with YUMI under WINE seems to work fine, I've always had trouble setting up a fresh flash drive with YUMI under WINE, but maybe it's just me. Also, on one of my computers (Kubuntu 64-bit 3.8.0-31-generic) sometimes I would navigate around and the WINE file manager thing wouldn't see any files or hidden folders. If this hapens to you, paste the exact name of what it is you want to select (like "gparted-live-0.14.1-6-i486.iso" or ".hiddenfolder" and hit enter.

Comment: The second option is very unlikely to me, because I'm a lot noobier than you (is that a valid english word? lol I don't understand english properly though). I'll give the first option a try.

Comment: I got a "Failed to install syslinux, your flash drive won't be bootable" message when I try this.  That's likely because the usb key is'nt exposed directly to wine, only the partition.  If the boot sector has already been written on a windows version, it just copies files, so it works.