# How to make USB devices visible to Wine application?

Tags: usb, wine

USB devices:

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b8:013c Seiko Epson Corp.

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 19a8:2036 Biforst Technology Inc.

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a61:3850 Abbott Diabetes Care

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

The problem concerns the four position. Dedicated Windows application "FreeStyle Auto-Assist Neo" can't see plugged device (glucometer).

Comment: Did you try [How to mount USB flash drive to WINE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314205/how-to-mount-usb-flash-drive-to-wine)

Comment: Yes, but rebuld wine is out of my possibilities. And this device is not a type of flash drive but it's a diabetic meter with (as I think) it's own protocol to communicate with dedicated program.